# Animate jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день/вечер.

На мой взгляд, достаточно сложный вопрос. Имеется `div`, нужно для jquery события hover прописать `animate` изменение высоты, ширины и позиции (`top` и `left`), когда же блок теряет курсор возвращать высоту, ширину и позицию обратно. В общем-то с этим проблемы нет, вот как я это сделал:

```
$('#button').hover(function () {
    $('#button').animate({
        width: '+=20px',
        height: '+=20px',
        left: '-=10px',
        top: '-=10px'
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $('#button').animate({
        width: '-=20px',
        height: '-=20px',
        left: '+=10px',
        top: '+=10px'
    }, 200);
})
```

Собственно вот в чем вопрос: мне нужно изменять все величины не в пикселях, а в процентах. Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. Немного поясню, зачем нужно позиционирование: блок увеличивается, а его центральная точка остается неизменной. Как-то так.

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZHzR/10/

Comment: Пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) закиньте. Потому как ваш код, какой-то загадочный, а когда дошёл до слов "*Немного поясню ... *", то совсем стало грустно.

Comment: Вот http://jsfiddle.net/2ZHzR/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, это не сложно. Переделаю ваш пример под проценты:

```
var w = $(this).width(),  //ширина картинки
    h = $(this).height(), //высота картинки
    zoom = 0.5; //зум картинки. это означает увеличение на 50%

$(this, '#buttons a').animate({
    width: w+w*zoom,
    height: h+h*zoom,
    left: "-="+(w*zoom/2),
    top: "-="+(h*zoom/2)
}, 200, 'easeOutElastic');
},
function () {
    $(this, '#buttons a').animate({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        left: "+="+(w*zoom/2),
        top: "+="+(h*zoom/2)
    }, 200, 'easeOutElastic');
```

Вот переписал первый попавшийся в гугле пример под процентное увеличение [мой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/TGX8J/1/) (пример из гугла с [абсолютным смещением](http://superdit.com/2011/06/11/hover-image-zoom-with-jquery/))

[Вот, собственно, ваш пример переделанный на фидле](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZHzR/12/)

Comment: Прошу прощения, еще один вопрос по этой теме. Если быстро водить курсором по всем объектом, то они "ломаются" и смещаются. Причем в этом примере /superdit.com/2011/06/11/hover-image-zoom-with-jquery/ все ок. Как это исправляется?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что это из-за процентного измерения.

Comment: Ха! Проблема решена: $(this).stop(true, true);